# How to create printable pages of front-and-back cards in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, double-sided, imposition

I need to create some simple game cards in ConTeXt. The data is stored in a macro, e.g. `\gamecard{front text}{back text}`, and when printed, the page is simply cut into 3x4 squares, and the "front text" items are printed all on one side and "back text" all on the other side.

The entire document is quite simple, like this:

```
\gamecard{Name 3 animals that live in the sea}{Move ahead 3 spaces}
\gamecard{Name 2 things you would bring to a deserted island}{Move ahead 2 spaces}
\gamecard{Name 5 things found in space}{Move ahead 5 spaces}
\gamecard{Name 6 things that can fly}{Move ahead 6 spaces}
\gamecard{Name 2 things that drive on the road}{Move ahead 2 spaces}
\gamecard{Name 5 things found in a tree}{Move ahead 5 spaces}
```

https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Imposition shows how to divide the page, but I don't know how to make it alternate pages, so page 1 is front text and page 2 is back text, then page 3 has more front text, page 4 has more back text, etc.

How can I create simple front-and-back printed cards in ConTeXt?

Comment: To save us some time, would it be possible to prepare an almost compilable MWE using solutions displayed in the wiki page? This is indeed an interesting problem, but I would like to have a template to work with.